Add name to auto message after submitting contact form
i used the jobs for wordpress plugin for generating a wordpress-career-page. Concerning the plugin it is generally possible to edit the notification message (the message an applicant sees directly after pressing the submitting button). But how can i use the name of the specific applicant in this message to be more personell. I tried
{job_applicant_name}

, which unfortunately does not work (it works for regular confirmation emails).
code for the input field of the name of the applicant:
<input id="input-name_name" type="text" name="job_applicant_name" data-jobinput="name_name" class="modal-input-text input-name_name input-reqired" value="" placeholder="">

My idea was to add an html code (label?) to the notification text, like Hello {job_applicant_name} (which obviously did not work) Any ideas?
{job_applicant_name} 

i also tried that: 

<body>
    <label for="job_applicant_name">Hello:</label>
    <span id="applicantName"></span>

    <script>
       
        var applicantName = document.getElementsByName('job_applicant_name')[0].value;

        document.getElementById('applicantName').innerText = applicantName;
    </script>
</body>

it only shows "Hello:"
what i also tried is the following:


<script>
    function personalizeConfirmation() {
        var name = document.getElementsByName('job_applicant_name')[0].value;

        var confirmationMessage = document.getElementById('job-apply-confirmation');

        confirmationMessage.innerHTML = '<p>Hallo ' + name + ',</p>' +
                                         '<p>vielen Dank für Ihre Bewerbung.<br>' +
                                         'Ihre Bewerbung ist uns wichtig und wird von uns in Kürze geprüft werden. ' +
                                         'Wir werden Sie über den Stand Ihrer Bewerbung auf dem Laufenden halten und in Kürze kontaktieren!<br>' +
                                         'Für Rückfragen können Sie sich zwischenzeitlich gerne an uns wenden.</p>';
    }

 var submitButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button job-submit');
    for (var i = 0; i < submitButtons.length; i++) {
        submitButtons[i].addEventListener('click', personalizeConfirmation);
    }

</script>



This does not work either.
Relevant elements:


<button class="button job-submit" type="submit">Bewerbung absenden</button>

//whole message
<div id="job-apply-confirmation">

//textfield
<input id="input-name_name" type="text" name="job_applicant_name" data-jobinput="name_name" class="modal-input-text input-name_name input-reqired" value="" placeholder=""



I think the javascript "addins" do not really work, because only the html <> elements are shown in the text field after the submission. Any ideas?
Would it be an idea to edit the phps of the plugin?
Thanks in Advance!

Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this information on how to ask a good question. The first point I'd like to highlight is that this is not a "please help me fix my problem" site, it is a Q+A site, so you need to ask one specific question that has a factual answer. The second point is that Stack Overflow has a sister site dedicated to WordPress questions.

The third point is that on the WordPress Q+A site, questions about third-party plugins are considered off-topic. The appropriate place to ask questions regarding third-party plugins is on the forum provided by the plugin vendor.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
